# How to find first duplicate row in a table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server. I have a table, that contains around 75000 records. Among them there are several duplicate records. So i wrote a query to know which record repeated how many times like,

`SELECT [RETAILERNAME],COUNT([RETAILERNAME]) as Repeated FROM [Stores] GROUP BY [RETAILERNAME]`

It gives me result like,

```
---------------------------
RETAILERNAME  |  Repeated
---------------------------
    X         |    4
---------------------------
    Y         |    6
---------------------------
    Z         |    10
---------------------------
```

Among 4 record(s) of X record, i need take only first record of X.

so here i want to retrieve all fields from first row of duplicate records. i.e. Take all records whose  RETAILERNAME='X' we will get some no. of duplicate records, we need to get only first row from them. 
Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Something like

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  [RETAILERNAME],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [RETAILERNAME] ORDER BY [RETAILERNAME]) RowID
        FROM    [Stores ]
)
SELECT  *
FROm    Vals
WHERE   RowID = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/259fc/4)

You can then also remove the duplicates if need be (**BUT BE CAREFUL THIS IS PERMANENT**)

```
;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  [RETAILERNAME],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [RETAILERNAME] ORDER BY [RETAILERNAME]) RowID
        FROM    Stores 
)
DELETE
FROM  Vals
WHERE RowID > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [retailername], 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY [retailername] 
                    ORDER BY [retailername])'RowRank' 
         FROM   [retailername]) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can write query as under

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Stores] GROUP BY [RETAILERNAME]
HAVING your condition